# ASP.NET Entity Framework 4 Navigation Entity not reflecting changes made to database

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I have two database tables (NEWS and NEWS_IMAGES) that I have produced an entity model for with a one to many association made between them in the model.

However when I query the model using the Navigation property (NEWS_IMAGES) it doesn't return any recent database inserts but if I query the navigation entity itself then I get all latest changes.

First Method using Navigation property:

```
IEnumerable<NEWS_IMAGES> imgs = dal.NEWS.Where(n => n.NEWS_ID == NewsID).FirstOrDefault().NEWS_IMAGES;
```

Second method using the actual entity (returns all recent changes):

```
IEnumerable<NEWS_IMAGES> imgs = dal.NEWS_IMAGES.Where(i => i.News_ID == NewsID)
```

This is the code that inserts a record to the NEWS_IMAGES entity:

```
NEWS_IMAGES img = new NEWS_IMAGES
            {
                News_ID = newsID,
                News_Image_Filename_Small = file_Sm,
                News_Image_Filename_Medium = file_Med,
                News_Image_Filename_Large = file_Lrge,
                News_Image_Order = imgCnt + 1
            };
            dal.NEWS_IMAGES.AddObject(img);
            dal.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Is `imgs` in the first example `null` or does it contain elements but not all which are in the database? In the first case and if you don't use lazy loading you need to include the navigation property: `dal.NEWS.Include("NEWS_IMAGES").Where...`. In the second case, I don't know. it's likely then that more details are needed to track down the problem.

Comment: `imgs` isn't null in either scenarios. The problem is that it doesn't contain any new records (when the first line of code used) that have just been added to the Database. Have tried the `include` option but still the same. Lazy Loading is enabled on the main edmx model.

Comment: It might be helpful if you could show the `NEWS` and `NEWS_IMAGE` classes and the code how you insert new entities to the context.

Comment: @Slauma - have now added code sample of how I insert a record

Comment: Hm, somehow it looks as if `News_ID` of `NEWS_IMAGES` class were not the foreign key to the `NEWS` entity. Did you check if the data including foreign key values are actually correct in the database after the Insert? What do you mean exactly with "recent" changes? Does that mean that when you restart the application and run your first query above, the referenced images collection is complete and contains all data?

Comment: Yes, if I restart the app all the newly inserted image records appear when I run the first query. So it sounds like some sort of caching is happening ???

Comment: I have no idea anymore. The first query usually works, even directly after the insert and within the same context instance. Try to add more code and info (about model and configuration and so on) so that it's perhaps possible to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3):

The default behavior of the EF is to load only the entity directly accessed by the application (e.g. News). IF the EF loaded all the related entities (e.g. News_Images) you will end up loading more entities than you actually need.
You can uses something called *eager loading* to load related entities using the **Include()** method. 
In your case you will have something like this:

```
var imgs= dal.NEWS.Include("NEWS_IMAGES").Where(n => n.NEWS_ID == NewsID).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try using the following which should do the trick:

```
IEnumerable<NEWS_IMAGES> imgs = 
   dal.NEWS.Where(n => n.NEWS_ID == NewsID).SelectMany(i => i.NEWS_IMAGES)
```